# No internet connection on host when Ethernet is Bridge for Guest VM (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge, virt-manager

I setup a bridged connection modifying the netplan file in /etc/netplan/ and setup the bridge device using `nmcli`. Below is my netplan file:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: true

  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      interfaces: enp0s31f6
```

And here is the output for my connections from nmcli (this is when br0 is down):

```
NAME                    UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE    
Wired connection 1      45db06a6-f1ea-4951-a761-abc167fa35e1  ethernet  enp0s31f6 
virbr0                  c7b49d1e-ac07-4591-a33b-b214920df215  bridge    virbr0    
br0                     92db226f-e302-44c2-be4a-8dd3a5df60a7  bridge    --        
bridge-slave-enp0s31f6  2bbef13e-b014-4e32-8457-1e3f97509870  ethernet  --        
ZR-NN24                 935c2479-ea90-421d-a00b-4f6206bae169  wifi      --
```

This is so I can RDP to a Win10 VM from my laptop. The VM is using QEMU/KVM and I use virt-manager to make changes to the VM as needed.

I also added the bridge connection to virt-manager by creating a xml file and using `virsh`. The XML file is below:

```
<network>
  <name>br0</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0" />
</network>
```

The issue is when I bring up the bridge using the following commands I no longer have a internet connection on the host:

```
nmcli con down Wired\ Connection\ 1
nmcli con up br0
```

The Win10 guest will be reachable to RDP when I start the VM and wait a few seconds. I am starting to think that this is a limitation with bridge connections - the host can't use the device that's bridge, but I am not sure since on 18.04 I was able to bridge the connection and the host was still able to communicate out to the internet on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to bring up your bridge slave connection

```
sudo nmcli con up bridge-slave-enp0s31f6
```

and you might have to init IP address via DHCP, but that's rare

```
sudo dhclient
```